# Azure Media Service Fairplay V3 DRM Content Key Policy

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, drm, fairplay

I'm trying to encrypt my live streaming content using DRM encryption by following instruction from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-protect-hls-with-fairplay.

This is my DRM policies and the streaming locator:

[image]

[image]

I'm able to get the MANIFEST file from the HLS URL. I found that should have another line (known as License URL?) something similar to the following, but it's not appearing inside my downloaded MANIFEST file:

```
#EXT-X-SESSION-KEY:METHOD=SAMPLE-AES,KEYFORMAT="com.apple.streamingkeydelivery",KEYFORMATVERSIONS="1",URI="skd://willzhanmswest.keydelivery.westus.media.azure.net/FairPlay/?kid=90e91c74-feb1-41ed-920a-3330a62279ca"
```

Is it something wrong when I configured the DRM? For the FAIRPLAY I uploaded .pfx file, password is in STRING format and the ASK is as given by APPLE. Is this correct or is there anything I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. The URI="skd://willzhanmswest.keydelivery.westus.media.azure.net/FairPlay/?kid=90e91c74-feb1-41ed-920a-3330a62279ca" is indeed the FairPlay license acquisition URL. sdk is per Apple's FPS spec.

If player SDK does not require explicit license URL, it knows to replace skd by https.

If player SDK requires explicit license URL, your code needs to replace skd by https.

Quick note: you are using OpenRestriction for 3 DRMs. I assume this is just for test and do not intend to do the same with production?

Comment: yeah its just for testing, but the issue now is the URI is not showing inside the file

Comment: If it is not showing up in the top level HLS manifest, check into the second level (playlist level, any of the bitrate).

Comment: 2nd level? how and where to check?

Comment: Suppose this is the FairPlay protected URL: https://eventgridmediaservice-usw22.streaming.media.azure.net/efcb9913-c181-4449-8f04-72522a47587f/MicrosoftElite01.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl,encryption=cbcs-aapl) In its playlist, you will find, for each bitrate, there is a URI attribute with a value like: QualityLevels(385752)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes,encryption=cbcs-aapl) .

Comment: Then you concatenate the video URL (up to manifest) with this segment, to get a URL like below for the specific bitrate: https://eventgridmediaservice-usw22.streaming.media.azure.net/efcb9913-c181-4449-8f04-72522a47587f/MicrosoftElite01.ism/QualityLevels(385752)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes,encryption=cbcs-aapl). This is the 2nd level playlist. For this particular protected asset, you can see the license acquisition URL at both levels.